# forcing cmake install through add_dependencies?

Tags: cmake

I'm sorry if this is duplicate. I see a lot of post that are similar, but I am either not "getting" it or it is not exactly the same issue.
I need to build two shared libraries.  They are in the same directory structure, and they both get but in to bin.  One is dependent on the other.

I've been reading up on add_dependencies, but that seems to deal with project builds outside of cmake.  These are both inside

Directory structure

```
src
  CMakeLists.txt
  bin
  xml
    CMakeLists.txt
    XML.c
    utils.c
    XMLSPCL.c
```

src/CMakelists.txt

```
set (BIN_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
add_subdirectory(xml/shrxml)
```

xml/CMakeLists.txt (AFTER the suggestion below)

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
project(shrxml)
    add_library(shrxml SHARED XML.c utils.c)
    install(TARGETS shrxml LIBRARY DESTINATION ${BIN_DIR})

project(shrxmlSPCL)
    add_dependencies(shrxmlSPCL shrxml)
    add_library(shrxmlSPCL SHARED XMLSPCL.c)
    target_link_libraries(shrxmlSPCL LINK_PUBLIC shrxml)
    install(TARGETS shrxmlSPCL LIBRARY DESTINATION ${BIN_DIR})
```

I can get it to work, but I know there has to be a correct way to do this.
To get it to work, I:

```
comment out the xmlSPCL project
cmake ..
make shrxml
run make install so I can get shrxml.so in to the bin directory
un-comment out xmlSPCL
make (again)
make install (again)
```

What I want is to run make once, have the shrxml.so go into the bin dir so that when shrxmlSPCL is linked, it sees the dependent lib.  Can that be done with the extra steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make an example project run I had to make 3 things different

1.
    target_link_libraries(shrxmlSPCL LINK_PUBLIC shrxml)

-> So neither *lib* nor *.so* as prefix/suffix

2.
    add_dependencies(shrxmlSPCL shrxml)

-> somewhere below the *add_library()* having the dependency

3.
install(TARGETS shrxmlSPCL LIBRARY DESTINATION ${BIN_DIR})
-> add LIBRARY  into your install command [doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/install.html#installing-targets)

Comment: I get this error on the add_dependencies line ` Cannot add target-level dependencies to non-existent target "shrxmlSPCL".

  The add_dependencies works for top-level logical targets created by the
  add_executable, add_library, or add_custom_target commands.  If you want to
  add file-level dependencies see the DEPENDS option of the add_custom_target
  and add_custom_command commands.`  <br>  I will investigate add_custom

Comment: *add_dependency* has to be after add_library the *add_library* which has the dependency. Sorry, i didn't tell exactly